# Cocos: How to detect touch input inside of a area/layout

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have several cocos layouts they are various panels or menus. I was wondering how to close then with a touch input outside of their area like most apps.

Basically how to close a popup menu by tapping any empty area on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you calculate the spaces between the edges of the screen and your popup and then call the destructor.

**This is how I do it:**

In init

```
auto touchListener = cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
touchListener->setSwallowTouches(true);
touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(CLASS::onTouch, this);
Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener, this);
```

On Touch

```
bool CLASS::onTouch(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    int ySize = visibleSize.height - holder->getContentSize().height;
    int locationY = touch->getLocation().y;
    if((locationY > 0 && locationY < ySize/2) || (locationY > origin.y + ySize/2 + holder->getContentSize().height && locationY < visibleSize.height))
    {
        this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) really appreciated.